# What is the real purpose of AndroidManifest.xml according to activities and their insantiation?

Tags: java, android

Is the Android Manifest responsible for the instantiation of all activities and other components as soon as the application starts? Or are they all instantiated as they are needed while the app is already running?

My hypothesis is that the Android manifest takes all the component declarations and creates instances of each and every one of them as soon as the application starts, so that when they are eventually called using a `startActivity(someIntent)` they are ready to proceed with their `onCreate()`, `onStart()` etc. The instance of the component, however, already exists.

Anyways, if it does not happen this way, how does it really work? When are components and their resepective classes instantiated?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your time and for commenting. However, I have already checked it and it still does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the manifest simply tells the system which components your app has available and the types of `Intent` objects for which it will respond.  The components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `ContentProvider`) are created on-demand when needed.  This is a better bit of background on the way Android handles app components and creation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Here's some additional info about how it creates processes for apps: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the information you have provided. So, according to what you have said, at what point during the instantiation of a component, such as an activity, does the system check for the android manifest?

Comment: It actually takes the manifest contents and tracks the information within the  PackageManagerService running within the framework.  As an example, when something calls `startActivity()` it is actually sending the request to the ActivityManagerService running within the framework.  That services works with the PackageManagerService to find a matching application (based on `Intent` contents and installed app `IntentFilter`s.)  It also checks security parameters and assuming it finds a match then the AcitivityManagerService will start the necessary application and deliver the `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is precisely what I was just about to suggest as an answer to my own question. Just to be sure,by "application" in "finding a matching application" you mean any component  and its name right?

Comment: Almost.  It's the combination of package name + signing certificate which make it an application.  The components are just pieces of the app.  Each of the components, when activated, are created automatically by the system and run within the same process.  Note that you can have multiple instances of the same component simultaneously as well (typically happens with activities.)

Comment: Alright I get it, but at what point does it check the actual name of an individual component as specified in the AndroidManifest.xml to verify whether it can be used or not? I assume within the same startActivity() method with help of the ActivityManagerService but you only mentioned it checking for the application itself and its containing package. Sorry for asking so many questions, I just want to get it as right as possible, thank you.

Comment: So, in case the app is already running and it needs to start a new activity, will the ActivityManagerService validate the existance of the component to be started within the AndroidManifest.xml. This taking into account information acquired from the intent parameters passed in? Therefore I guess the system has to check for the Android Manifest every time an activity is started.

Comment: `startActivity()` actually calls across a `Binder` interface to the ActivityManagerService running in the system_server process.  ActivityManagerService manages launching of apps (components) as well as the task/back stack the user sees.  It determines what gets launched using the contents of the `Intent` as well as information from the PackageManagerService (also running inside of system_server.)  If the app to be started already has a running process, then it is notified that a component is to be created/started rather than create a new process.

Comment: Of course, the `Intent` and the manifest can carry additional flags which are used to tweak this behavior, such as always starting a new task stack.